# Is this a php memory leak?

Tags: php, memory-leaks

**UPDATE** I noticed that with a particular require_once('myobject.php') that the memory increase showed up. This require_once() was run conditionally. When I moved the require_once()statement out of the if statement so it loads all the time, the memory increase went away. Doesn't make sense to me, but the issue is solved. I'm not sure this is actually an "answer" so I will leave it unanswered.

I have `memory_get_usage()` in the footer of my page and with each refresh of the page, I watch it increase by about 100k each time. My page load creates many objects and destroys them when done . My parent objects each have `__destruct()` which uses `unset()` with all child objects. Child objects with a reference back to the parent, have `__destruct()` to `unset()` these references.

Inserting `memory_get_usage()` before and after processing different parts of my page only tells me how much of the total usage was added due to that part of the script. How do I go about determining what memory is lost and not recycled for garbage collection after the page finishes loading?

I have one global $_SESSION var containing objects storing user info, but have verified using strlen(serialize($object)) that this object is not growing in size.

I presume that what I am seeing is a memory leak and that php garbage collection should be in effect after the script ends. Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but if you have a standard Apache and PHP setup, the PHP process is destroyed after the request finishes, so it doesn't use memory between requests. So `unset()` doesn't matter (across requests). This could be different for php-fpm, I'm not sure. But likely, there is no memory leak, but possibly some session file is increased in size so it is larger when it is loaded the next time.

Comment: @Matt why didn't you post that as an answer, it would have been a good answer.

Comment: Sure, I think my answer could be elaborated upon, but I posted it now as a starting point.

Comment: Bytecode caches like APC don't like conditional includes/requires; which is most likely the root cause of that memory usage increase. A lot depends on the exact implementation of the cache, for example
- cache all codepaths (i.e. parse file with and without inclusion and cache both paths)
- don't cache at all
- ...

Caching is pretty hard. Either way, the point is that this, to me, sounds like it could be related to a bytecode cache.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but if you have a standard Apache and PHP setup, the PHP process is destroyed after the request finishes, so it doesn't use memory between requests.

So `unset()`, `__destruct()`, etc. doesn't matter (across requests). When the PHP process ends, all memory is reclaimed.

But likely, there is no memory leak, but possibly some session file is increased in size so it is larger when it is loaded the next time.

*Note: This could be different for php-fpm, I'm not sure.*

Comment: Thanks for the input. I noticed that with a particular `require_once('myobject.php')` that the memory increase showed up. This `require_once()` was run conditionally. When I moved the `require_once()`statement out of the if statement so it loads all the time, the memory increase went away. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I don't know what the condition was. Or whether the increase of memory happened every time, or if it was only higher when this unknown condition was met. Was the memory increasing without bound after N reloads (where N is at least...10, 20, 100)?

Comment: The increase was 80k to 150k with every reload and I never found a limit - although I only tried maybe 30 times.

Comment: Not sure then. For all I know, `myobject.php` loads a file, reads it, and appends about 100k of data to it. Or more likely, stores more data in the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Including myobject.php did not run any code and the oddity was that it only happened with a conditional include. The same code was being included either way. Probably not worth worrying about - I will just include the code and leave it at that. Thanks for your help - your answer helps understand the process better even if it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Feel free to mark as accepted. If you do want to investigate further, I'd post the exact code that causes the issue on pastebin/gist (if possible to simplify it, the less code the better), and ask specifically why that causes the memory usage to go up with each request.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what was the actual size of this 'myobject.php' file?